# @for loop in a mixin in precss or sass

Tags: css, for-loop, sass, mixins, postcss

I have this great for loop in my precss style sheet. I would like to convert it to a mixin where i can pass the start values for $size (font-size) and $spacing(letter-spacing) for different media queries. I cannot get the variables to increment as i progress through the loop when i call it from a mixin. It works fine from the stylesheet

```
/*--adds .4 rem to each heading fz and character spacing 1-6---*/
$size: 1.8rem;
$spacing: 7px;
@for $i from 6 through 1 {
    h$i {
        font-size: resolve($size);
        letter-spacing: resolve($spacing);
        @extend %heading;
      }
        $size: $size + .4rem;
        $spacing: $spacing * 1.2;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your current code is close to working as a mixin when wrapped in a `@mixin` declaration in SCSS. The only tweak needed is outputting the `$i` in the selector using the `#{$variable}`

#### SCSS input:

```
%heading{
  /* heading properties */
  color: #999;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

@mixin headingSize($size: 1.8rem, $spacing: 7px){
  @for $i from 6 through 1{
    h#{$i}{
      @extend %heading;
      font-size: $size;
      letter-spacing: $spacing;
    }
    $size: $size + .4rem;
    $spacing: $spacing * 1.2;
  }
}

@include headingSize($size: 2rem, $spacing: 10px);
```

This example uses your original `$size` and `$spacing` variables as default parameters in the mixin.

Here's an [example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24gqyc9d/) in action.

#### CSS output:

```
h6, h5, h4, h3, h2, h1 {
  /* heading properties */
  color: #999;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  letter-spacing: 12px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 2.8rem;
  letter-spacing: 14.4px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  letter-spacing: 17.28px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 3.6rem;
  letter-spacing: 20.736px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  letter-spacing: 24.8832px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i am using precss and it doesn't appear to be working. I removed the punctuation.

### precess code:

`@define-mixin heading
$size: 1.8rem,
$spacing: 5px
{
  @for $i from 1 through 4 {
    h$i {
      @extend %heading;
        font-size: resolve($size);
        letter-spacing: resolve($spacing);
    }
    $size: $size - .4rem;
    $spacing: $spacing * .5;
  }
}`